# Breaking a list into smaller lists at a point

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-lists

I've written a function that takes for example [["a",1],["b",2],["a",2],["b",3]], where each small list has a letter and a number, and returns, [["a",1,2,"b",2,3]].

There is a lot more to this problem, but to make things simple, the next step is to turn this into a form [["a",3],["b",5]]. The second item of each smaller list, is the sum of the numbers between the letters ie 1,2 are associated with "a", 2,3 are associated with "b", as seen in the original list. The number of occurrences of a letter is unlimited.

Another example To summarize: function([["a",1,3,4,"b",2,2,"c",4,5]]) => [["a",8],["b",4],["c",9]]

Nothing I've written has come close to accomplishing this. This is a kind of bare-bones challenge, no list comprehension and nothing can be imported

Comment: one is normally expected to post _the code you tried_ AND how it failed to do what you want. PLEASE, post that info in your Question ... and use code formatting to make it readable.

Comment: The original format of your list is much easier to process. `for k, v in original: d[k] += v`, where `d = collections.defaultdict(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can help you:

```
# Assuming a random initial list:
data = [["a",1,3,4,4,2,"b",2,2,3,5,2,3,"c",4,3,5,5]]
# An empty list where it will be added the result:
new_data = []
# Variable to accumulate the sum of every letter:
sume = 0

# FOR loop to scan the "data" variable:
for i in data[0]:
    # If type of the i variable is string, we assume it's a letter:
    if type(i) == str:
        # Add accumulated sum
        new_data.append(sume)
        # We restart *sume* variable:
        sume = 0
        # We add a new letter read:
        new_data.append(i)
    else:
        # We accumulate the sum of each letter:
        sume += i

# We extract the 0 added initially and added the last sum:
new_data = new_data[1::]+[sume]

# Finally, separate values in pairs with a FOR loop and add it to "new_data2":
new_data2 = []
for i in range(len(new_data)//2):
    pos1 = i*2
    pos2 = pos1+1
    new_data2.append([new_data[pos1],new_data[pos2]])

# Print data and new_data2 to verify results:
print (data)
print (new_data2)
# Pause the script:
input()
```

This code can work once by script, but it can convert in a nested function to use it in the way you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It’s normally expected you post your solution first, but it seems that you have tried some things and need help. For future questions make sure you *include* your attempt, since it helps us provide more help as to *why* your solution doesn't work, and what additional steps you can take to improve your solution.

Assuming that your list always starts with a letter or `str`, and all numbers are of type `int`, you could use a dictionary to do the counting. I have added comments to explain the logic.

```
def group_consecutive(lst):
    groups = {}

    key = None
    for item in lst:

        # If we found a string, set the key and continue to next iteration immediately
        if isinstance(item, str):
            key = item
            continue

        # Add item to counts
        # Using dict.get() to initialize to 0 if ket doesn't exist
        groups[key] = groups.get(key, 0) + item

    # Replacing list comprehension: [[k, v] for k, v in groups.items()]
    result = []
    for k, v in groups.items():
        result.append([k, v])

    return result
```

Then you could call the function like this:

```
>>> group_consecutive(["a",1,3,4,"b",2,2,"c",4,5])
[['a', 8], ['b', 4], ['c', 9]]
```

A better solution would probably use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do the counting, but since you mentioned no imports then the above solution adheres to that.